# Incorrect version number apk

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android, apk

I have the following problem.
We have build an app with mono for android. The first version was no problem.
versionnumber was 1.0 and that is correct.

Meanwhile we have an update ready for this app. I changed the versionnumber in the manifest from '1' to '2'
and the versionname from '1.0' to '1.1'. But after I install the app on my phone I still see version '1.0'.

Also when I try to update de app in the market I get the error:
"The new apk's versioncode (1) already exists." (I'm sure I changed the versioncode to '2' in the manifest.)

What is going wrong?

Goldhorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have found the problem.

I had to include my AndroidManifest.xml in my .csproj file. After that I had to add some more configurations from the C# code to the androidmanifest. I now use both the C# attributes and a manual AndroidManifest (which will be combined by Mono for Android).

Answer (score 0):

Did you change `versionCumber` or `versionCode`?

The correct attribute is `versionCode` (I don't know about `versionNumber`):

```
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.1"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:installLocation="preferExternal"
          package="com.jamwarehouse.apps.evolution" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="0.1">
    <application android:label="Evolution">
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
</manifest>
```

Anyway, if you are using Mono for Android, you shouldn't need to edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` at all. You use C# attributes on your classes and you edit the version details via the project properties:

```
[Activity(Label = "Timeband", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class TimebandActivity : Activity
{
    ...
}
```

Note: I did notice that if I edited a field and then pressed close of the tab, it didn't save. You have to click out of the text boxes first, then close/save.

Comment: I changed both versionCode and versionName (versionName is what is shown on the phone in Settings > applications > app). 

The problem with change box before saving I had discovered also. Very annoying..